# Android notification, when pushed should open that activity

Tags: java, android, notifications

Im having problems with notifications in android. Im making a chat client.

when my client tells me that someone is chatting with me from a previous chat, and I push it, it opens up a new instance of that chat. I want it to work like the facebook mesenger, that is when I push the notification it opens up the chat for the person which is trying to speak to me, instead of an empty chat window.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your Notification you can set a Intent:

`Notification n;
n.setContentIntent(intent)`

In your intent you will set the activity that will be started and also you can put extras, like an ID of the conversation or something that can be identified latter.
Because when you start this new chat activity on `onCreate()` you need to check if there is extras, take the ID for example and search for your conversation history and write all your logic.